# Getting all selected values from an ASP ListBox

Tags: c#, asp.net, webforms, listbox

I have an ASP ListBox that has the SelectionMode set to "Multiple". Is there any way of retreiving ALL selected elements and not just the last one?

```
<asp:ListBox ID="lstCart" runat="server" Height="135px" Width="267px" SelectionMode="Multiple"></asp:ListBox>
```

Using `lstCart.SelectedIndex` just returns the last element (as expected). Is there something that will give me all selected?

Answer (score 63, accepted):

You can use the [ListBox.GetSelectedIndices method](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.listbox.getselectedindices.aspx) and loop over the results, then access each one via the items collection. Alternately, you can loop through all the items and check their [Selected property](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.listitem.selected.aspx).

```
// GetSelectedIndices
foreach (int i in ListBox1.GetSelectedIndices())
{
    // ListBox1.Items[i] ...
}

// Items collection
foreach (ListItem item in ListBox1.Items)
{
    if (item.Selected)
    {
        // item ...
    }
}

// LINQ over Items collection (must cast Items)
var query = from ListItem item in ListBox1.Items where item.Selected select item;
foreach (ListItem item in query)
{
    // item ...
}

// LINQ lambda syntax
var query = ListBox1.Items.Cast<ListItem>().Where(item => item.Selected);
```

Answer (score 2):

use GetSelectedIndices method of listbox

```
  List<int> selecteds = listbox_cities.GetSelectedIndices().ToList();

        for (int i=0;i<selecteds.Count;i++)
        {
            ListItem l = listbox_cities.Items[selecteds[i]];
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

try using this code I created using VB.NET :

```
Public Shared Function getSelectedValuesFromListBox(ByVal objListBox As ListBox) As String
    Dim listOfIndices As List(Of Integer) = objListBox.GetSelectedIndices().ToList()
    Dim values As String = String.Empty

    For Each indice As Integer In listOfIndices
        values &= "," & objListBox.Items(indice).Value
    Next indice
    If Not String.IsNullOrEmpty(values) Then
        values = values.Substring(1)
    End If
    Return values
End Function
```

I hope it helps.