# Get all selected items from asp.net ListBox

Tags: asp.net, listbox

Anyone know of a smooth way to get all of the **selected** items in a listbox control by using extension methods?

And, please, spare me the argument of *it's irrelevant as to how one gets such a list because in the end everything uses a loop to iterate over the items and find the selected ones anyway*.

Answer (score 29, accepted):

```
var selected = yourListBox.Items.GetSelectedItems();
//var selected = yourDropDownList.Items.GetSelectedItems();
//var selected = yourCheckBoxList.Items.GetSelectedItems();
//var selected = yourRadioButtonList.Items.GetSelectedItems();

public static class Extensions
{
    public static IEnumerable<ListItem> GetSelectedItems(
           this ListItemCollection items)
    {
        return items.OfType<ListItem>().Where(item => item.Selected);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 7):

Extension method:

```
public static List<ListItem> GetSelectedItems(this ListBox lst)
{
    return lst.Items.OfType<ListItem>().Where(i => i.Selected).ToList();
}
```

You can call it on your listbox like:

```
List<ListItem> selectedItems = myListBox.GetSelectedItems();
```

You could also do the conversion using a 'Cast' on the list box items like:

```
return lst.Items.Cast<ListItem>().Where(i => i.Selected).ToList();
```

Not sure which will perform better `OfType` or `Cast` (my hunch is `Cast`).

**Edit** based on Ruben's feedback for a generic ListControl method which would indeed make it much more useful extension method:

```
public static List<ListItem> GetSelectedItems(this ListControl lst)
{
    return lst.Items.OfType<ListItem>().Where(i => i.Selected).ToList();
}
```

Comment: You could also to replace `ListBox` for `ListControl`, so your extension works for all list controls, as `DropDownList`, `CheckBoxList`, `RadioButtonList` and so on

Comment: Good idea.. will adjust my answer to reflect that.

Comment: `Cast` is a bit faster, but can lead to `InvalidCastException`; seems Cast is applicable here, since `Items.Add` just receive `ListItem` objects

Answer (score 1):

Hello i've created one solution for this problem in this post using VB.NET:

[Getting all selected values from an ASP ListBox](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1586078/getting-all-selected-values-from-an-asp-listbox/35437619#35437619)

This code below is the same as the link above:

```
Public Shared Function getSelectedValuesFromListBox(ByVal objListBox As ListBox) As String
Dim listOfIndices As List(Of Integer) = objListBox.GetSelectedIndices().ToList()
Dim values As String = String.Empty

For Each indice As Integer In listOfIndices
    values &= "," & objListBox.Items(indice).Value
Next indice
If Not String.IsNullOrEmpty(values) Then
    values = values.Substring(1)
End If
Return values
End Function
```

I hope it helps.

Comment: Your first line doesn't compile in VS2015 for me; but replacing it with Dim listOfIndices() As Integer = objListBox.GetSelectedIndices() seems to do the trick