# How to check if a ListItem is selected?

Tags: c#, asp.net

I am making a mini quiz and I am stuck on the C# coding with checking which ListItem a user selected from a DropDownList.

```
            <li><b>What is 231 mod 55?</b>
                <asp:Label ID="lblQuestionResult2" runat="server" Font-Bold="true" Font-Size="16px" />
                <br />
                <asp:DropDownList ID="DropDownList1" runat="server" Width="55px">
                    <asp:ListItem>14</asp:ListItem>
                    <asp:ListItem>6</asp:ListItem>
                    <asp:ListItem>11</asp:ListItem>
                </asp:DropDownList>
            </li>
```

What I have doesn't work. How do go about checking what the user selects?

```
    if (ListItem.Equals(toString(11)))
    {
        lblQuestionResult2.ForeColor = System.Drawing.Color.Green;
        lblQuestionResult2.Text = "Correct";
    }
    else
    {
        lblQuestionResult2.ForeColor = System.Drawing.Color.Red;
        lblQuestionResult2.Text = "Incorrect";
    }
```

Comment: check this one out.http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1829935/get-all-selected-items-from-asp-net-listbox

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your `DropDownList` control is already a server side control. Add an event handler for the `OnSelectedIndexChanged` event and handle it. It should look like

```
  <asp:DropDownList ID="DropDownList1" 
       runat="server" Width="55px" AutoPostBack="true" 
       OnSelectedIndexChanged="OnComboSelectionChanged">
```

In the code behind you can add a handler like this

```
protected void OnComboSelectionChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
  // Your code goes here.
  string selectedValue = DropDownList1.SelectedValue;

}
```

Make sure you use

```
AutoPostBack="true"
```

Comment: Just curious, why do I need the AutoPostBack="true"

Comment: @then how do you going to get the values to server ? you need to send the values to the seerver for filterining. or else you can use jquery with ajax calls.

Comment: @trama 'AutoPostback' indicates whether a postback to the server will automatically occur when the user changes the selection.

Comment: @Ravi I am not sure i understood your question. If you are refering to all the items in the dropdown box, you can get it from the 'Items' property (which is a collection).

Answer (score 0):

There is two ways to get it:

```
 //One way
 string selectedvalue = ddList.SelectedValue;

 //Second Way
 string selectedindex = ddList.SelectedItem.Text;
```

The full example:

I have putted a `DropDownList` and a `Button`

```
 <asp:DropDownList ID="ddList" runat="server">
        <asp:ListItem>14</asp:ListItem>
        <asp:ListItem>6</asp:ListItem>
        <asp:ListItem>11</asp:ListItem>
 </asp:DropDownList>

 <asp:Button ID="btnClick" runat="server" Text="Button" OnClick="btnClick_Click" />
```

And i created a method which fired when the user clicks on the button

```
protected void btnClick_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{

     string selectedvalue = ddList.SelectedValue;
     string selectedindex = ddList.SelectedItem.Text;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This MSDN page should help. Looks like what you need to do
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.listitem.selected.aspx?cs-save-lang=1&cs-lang=csharp#code-snippet-2

Answer (score 0):

this might help you

//aspx side

```
 <asp:DropDownList ID="DropDownList1" runat="server" Width="55px" 
                   onselectedindexchanged="DropDownList1_SelectedIndexChanged">
                    <asp:ListItem>14</asp:ListItem>
                    <asp:ListItem>6</asp:ListItem>
                    <asp:ListItem>11</asp:ListItem>
                </asp:DropDownList>
```

//cs side

```
protected void DropDownList1_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (DropDownList1.SelectedValue=="11")
        {
            lblQuestionResult2.ForeColor = System.Drawing.Color.Green;
            lblQuestionResult2.Text = "Correct";
        }
        else
        {
            lblQuestionResult2.ForeColor = System.Drawing.Color.Red;
            lblQuestionResult2.Text = "Incorrect";
        }
    }
```

Comment: 'DropDownList1.SelectedValue' returns a string, so we might be able to get rid of that redundant '.ToString()' method call.

Answer (score 0):

```
<asp:DropDownList ID="DropDownList1" runat="server" Width="55px" 
               onselectedindexchanged="DropDownList1_SelectedIndexChanged">
                <asp:ListItem>14</asp:ListItem>
                <asp:ListItem>6</asp:ListItem>
                <asp:ListItem>11</asp:ListItem>
            </asp:DropDownList>
```

//The code behind

```
protected void DropDownList1_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (DropDownList1.SelectedIndex!=0)
    {
        //your code implementation for selected value
    }
}
```