# C# version of javascript multiselect

Tags: c#, asp.net, multi-select

can anyone point me in the right direction? I've been searching for a C# variant of the javascript multiselection box that is in this site --> [mulitselect](http://www.quasipartikel.at/multiselect/) <-- Searched all day but now my brains are wracked dry over this, and the javascript is way to complex for me to understand. Any help is welcome, even if it is something remotely similar, I need a C# variant. Thanks all.

EDIT:
Sorry I forgot to mention that part, it is for asp.net website

Comment: Uhh.. For winforms? WPF? ASP.net Control?

Comment: a little more info would be appreciated:) and would help others to reply..

Comment: @Nenotlep yeah sorry about that, completely forgot about that, I made an edit

Comment: C# is a language, not a framework - you mean .NET equivalent. So now you know the framework, the question then comes to what *technology* i.e. WinForms/WPF/ASP.NET etc?

Answer (score 0):

> it is for asp.net website

The control you are looking for is a [DropDownList](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.dropdownlist.aspx).

Answer (score 0):

A quick search on SO brought me  this ...

[Multi-select dropdown list in ASP.NET](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/774587/multi-select-dropdown-list-in-asp-net) and [Getting all selected values from an ASP ListBox](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1586078/getting-all-selected-values-from-an-asp-listbox)

Both links provide code to achieve the multiselect dropdownlist.